# Add character to existing font in Tesseract training

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Is there a way to add a character to an existing font that was trained for Tesseract OCR?
I just trained a new font, but it is misreading colons (':') as '2.'
  So, I would like to just train it to recognize the colon, without having to retrain everything I just trained.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incremental training in tesseract is not possible (adding some letters to existing data).

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00#fine-tuning-for--a-few-characters

Comment: Your link is valid for version 4+ but the question is posted when this version is not available. And there are still people which prefer to use version 3...

Comment: It can always help someone who refers to this question!